# Can someone find the flaw in my parallax code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, parallax

I found a cute 404 page on github that uses parallax effect, my copy shows fine but has no parallax movement; [404 starwars](http://www.rhgrafix.com/404starwars.htm) - It should move like this: [parallaxIllustration](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallaxIllustration) 
 I've tried everything to debug it, I cannot find the flaw in the code. Can someone please take a moment to find it?

Thanks!  R.L.Hamm

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: *Can someone find the flaw in my parallax code?* No. Why should we?

Comment: you have 23 error if you open the console and i think it's because of the image url check it

Comment: _Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d0trqN//S9M2ek/FckP9vfjlA==' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback._

Answer (score 2):

Hamm, Please include the   https://github.com/_error.js in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/_error.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: These is the JavaScript for the animation